# How to add custom properties to SonarQube Project

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any way to add custom properties a SonarQube project while the analysis is being pushed or during project creation from APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You're either looking for [Custom Measures](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Custom+Measures) or need to [write your own plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+a+Plugin).